# Correlation between Tensor products over a Ring and it's subring

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm intrested in finding out what the correlation between the two tensor products 
$$ M \otimes_R  N \quad and \quad M \otimes_S N \quad $$ 
is.(R,S are Rings and S is a subring of R)
I know that we can construct a surjective Homomorphism $\phi : M\otimes_R N \to M\otimes_S N$
Now i just used the isomorphism theorem to derive $M\otimes _{ R }N\quad \cong \quad M\otimes _{ S }N/ker\quad \phi) $
Is this really all there is or can we say more things about their correlation

Comment: What are $R$ and $S$?

Comment: Sorry R and S are Rings and S is a Subring of R

Comment: There are a lot of fairly complicated rings.  My guess is that this question is complicated enough not to have a non-trivial answer.